# TYPO3: Disable language labels in backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

In Typo3, is there any way I can disable the language labels next to the content elements?

[image: language label]

Or even better: Is there a way to disable all language features for a single-language site? Though the other language options are not that important as I can disable them via Page TSConfig.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to disable all language features since even if you only have one language. You need some language specific settings, e.g. `locale` for date formatting or `typo3Language` to get the proper translation of labels in the frontend.

Nevertheless, you can change the label next to the flag:

1. Go to the Sites module on the left side
2. Select your site configuration
3. Go to the "Languages" tab
4. Select your language
5. Change the title, e.g. to Deutsch

Comment: Yes, I know I can change the label, but as I am not allowed to put an empty title there I can't disable it this way, there is no empty/none flag icon either. I know it has to be possible because I can find pictures without the label (at least from TYPO3 9)

Comment: In TYPO3 < 10.4 the flag for the default language was configured via TSConfig. This possibility is gone with 10.4. See the big warning box in the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/Mod.html#defaultlanguagelabel).

Comment: @PeterKraume How to hide flag from backend as shown in question screenshot, if we have only one language

Comment: As I've already written: if you use TYPO3 v10 or v11 that's NOT possible by configuration. If you're using composer you could use `cweagans/composer-patches` and patch the core manually. But I would not recommend that. If it's so important for you to hide the flag, file a feature request for v12 in the [issue tracker](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues).

Comment: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/93242 Task #93242 Remove language information in page + list module if no multilanguage site